# Mobs aren't spawning in my Minecraft PE Server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I created a new Minecraft PE Server and no mobs are spawning in my server; neither passive or hostile mobs, *not even tall grass*.

The difficulty is not peaceful and I have restarted the server.

We also spawned in a zombie in the daytime with a zombie egg, but it didn't try to attack us nor did it burn in the sun.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of  the zombie.

Comment: How could I transfer screenshots from my IOS device to my computer?

Comment: You can use iCloud picture sharing so that you can access your pictures with iTunes app on your computer or download the free [Stack Exchange](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) app to your phone.

Comment: I will post it once I get the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Minecraft PE servers don't have any official hosting method. You might have to ask this question on the site where you got your hosting tool. Or at least tell us what tool you're using so we can give answers made for that tool.

Comment: @EatMyTacoCrumbs I think that the only hosting method is this: https://www.pocketmine.net/

Comment: @ardaozkal I think you might be right, but we should wait for confirmation from the original poster.

Comment: @EatMyTacoCrumbs also It'd be great if he/she mentioned the platform he/she ran the server and the version of the server. For example pocketmine supports Windows, Linux, Mac, Android and iOS (with Jailbreak).

Comment: @ardaozkal I wrote an answer that is about PocketMine, I hope it applies to the asker's hosting tool.

Answer (score 2):

As of April 18, 2015, PocketMine does not support mobs. It does not spawn mobs naturally, you must use a spawn egg, but then it won't move. The developers are working on this feature but until then you will have to wait. PocketMine doesn't spawn anything naturally including all types of mobs, tall grass, and fire**. This applies to all platforms that PocketMine supports.

** Fire doesn't burn the block that it was placed on either.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I was using the leet server hosting app and noticed that with peaceful off and both passive and aggressive mobs weren't spawning. At that time is when I did some research and found out that leet actually uses pocketmine for their servers, because you can choose how you want your server hosted on the android version and change it, but can't on iOS. They are planning to add support in the future. Hope this helped.